# Running same python script multiple times mixes variables

Tags: python

I want to pass some data to another python script and do something there. But the data i send conflicts if i run script multiple times at the same time with different arguments. How do i separate them?

Example code:

**main.py**

```
import otherscript

list_a = [1,2,3] # from arguments
otherscript.append_to_another_list(list_a)
```

**otherscript.py**

```
another_list = []
def append_to_another_list(list):
    another_list.append(list)
    print(another_list)
```

if i run main.py twice at the same time with arguments 1,2,3 and 4,5,6 it prints both of them in the same list like [1,2,3,4,5,6]. I hope i made this clear

Comment: What do you mean at the same time? How do you run it at the same time?

Comment: i run `main.py -l 123` and then `main.py -l 456` on another terminal window, and second one prints both of them

Comment: what is `-l` flag ? You should have included that in your `main.py` example

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh it's very hard to include actual code here so i wanted to simplify question. Main issue is `otherscript` 's `another_list` variable is shared between instances and it should be independent for each `main.py` file is running which is a infinite loop in my example

Comment: @ggnoredo  `another_list.append(list)`   this code appends new `list` into 'another_list`.   Could you let me know more detail what you want to solve?

Comment: Is there a simpler way you can solve your problem?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh yes but each running `main.py` is appending into the same `another_list` . What i want is to make them separate

Comment: I am unable to replicate it, Also you can never run two commands at the exact same time, there will always be a delay between you entering the two commands in a different terminal, something else is going on

Comment: See what I tried in my answer below!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of you invoke this twice from the OS command line - say, `bash` - you would expect them to be totally independent, **not** showing the behaviour the OP describes.

On the other hand, within a single Python interpreter, a module is only initialised the once, so the list in your `otherscript` module (which is a module rather than a script) will stick around, and keep being appended to.

In any case, perhaps your best option for finer control would be a class.

```py
class ListKeeper:
    def __init__(self):
        self.another_list = []

    def append_to_another_list(self, list):
        self.another_list.append(list)
        print(another_list)
```

Your `main.py` would look like:

```py
import otherscript

list_a = [1,2,3] # from arguments
keeper1 = otherscript.ListKeeper()
keeper1.append_to_another_list(list_a)
```

You can create as many instances as you need, all independent of one another, and all keeping their own state.

Answer (score 1):

I just simplified your `main.py` as follows

```
import otherscript

import sys
list_a = [int(item) for item in sys.argv[1:]]
otherscript.append_to_another_list(list_a)
```

And then when I run them together using `python3.7 main.py 1 2 3 && python3.7 main.py 4 5 6` I get the output

```
[[1, 2, 3]]
[[4, 5, 6]]
```

In addition, if you open the same terminal and run the `append_to_another_list` command twice, the output will change, since you are  referring to the same list!

```
In [2]: import otherscript                                                      

In [3]: otherscript.append_to_another_list([1,2,3])                             
[[1, 2, 3]]

In [4]: otherscript.append_to_another_list([4,5,6])                             
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Comment: I agree, running the OP's code as shown from the command line behaves like this. I wonder if they are running their code some other way, not from the raw command line, such that both are within a single Python process.

Comment: Yes, you can never `run` two commands at the same terminal, as the OP states in the comments as well!